# SQL query - normalization

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to selectively transpose individual months columns (Jan, Feb, March) into a single new column as Month. What SQL queries should I use to do this?

**Input:**

```
Item   |Measure |Jan |Feb  |Mar  |Apr  |May  |Jun  |Jul  |Aug  |Sep  |Oct  |Nov  |Dec |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
110053 | sales  |559 |1738 |755  |769  |519  |919  |519  |709  |779  |589  |519  |699 |
110053 | gm     |333 |790  |452  |457  |309  |547  |309  |422  |459  |350  |309  |416 |
110053 | cost   |56  |234  |75   |77   |52   |92   |52   |71   |79   |59   |52   |70  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: You need the unpivot functionality, in whichever database you are working.

Comment: Oracle Sql database

Comment: Posting a picture of your data shows very little effort on your part to get help. Please review this discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question If you want more than @EzequielLópezPetrucci already gave you, give us more to work with to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You need the unpivot clause:

```
select *
  from table
unpivot
(
  quantity
    for month in (Jan,Feb,Mar.... [fill out all the months columns)
)
```

Comment: Didnt know about the unpivot construct. Works on oracle 11g+. Cool thing! +1. A Link to a documentation would be even nicer.

Comment: Hi Renato ,  thanks for your reply . Can you provide me exact query for the data I posted since I'm very new to sql programming ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem:

```
select Item,Month,sales,gm,cost 
from (
        select Item,Measure,Month,sales,
        CASE Month 
             WHEN 'JAN' Then 1
             WHEN 'FEB' THEN 2 
             WHEN 'MAR' THEN 3 
             WHEN 'APR' THEN 4 
             WHEN 'MAY' THEN 5 
             WHEN 'JUN' THEN 6 
             WHEN 'JUL' THEN 7 
             WHEN 'AUG' THEN 8 
             WHEN 'SEP' THEN 9 
             WHEN 'OCT' THEN 10 
             WHEN 'NOV' THEN 11 
             WHEN 'DEC' THEN 12
         ELSE 0
         END Month_num
   FROM (select Item,Measure,Month,sales
      from Table1
      unpivot
      (
        sales
        for Month in (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec)
       )
    )
)
pivot 
(
   sum(sales)
   for Measure in ('sales' AS Sales,'gm' AS gm,'cost' AS cost)
)
ORDER BY Month_num
```

To know more about the pivot and unpivot use below link:

> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

For demo Follow the link:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b4e2/25

Comment: @Andy Try the above solution.